# Does selenium with rspec have a pause or hold feature?

Tags: selenium, rspec

I'm using rspec and selenium. Is there soemthing like a pause button I can put in my test so I can interact with the page while I'm developing a test?

Answer (score 0):

Now this is not the most optimal solution, but I found it useful to throw in a breakpoint statement in the middle of the test. This allows for inspection of the document in the browser or/and values inside your code.

I use pry for the debugging and have my Rails test environment set to not cache classes. This allows for quick modifications and browser (capybara forks a separate thread) refreshes. Here is a relevant portion of my Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do 
  gem 'rspec-rails', github: 'rspec/rspec-rails'
  gem "factory_girl_rails" # factorygirl instead of fixtures
  gem "guard-rspec"        # automaticly running the specs when file is saved
  gem 'grizzled-rails-logger', github: 'bmc/grizzled-rails-logger'
  gem "faker"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara", github: 'jnicklas/capybara' # simulating a user
  gem 'database_cleaner'   # cleans the database
  gem 'launchy'
end                        # remember to install rb-fsevent if your on a mac

group :epic_console do
  gem 'pry'             # remember to look in development.rb
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-doc'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'hirb-unicode'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'pry-coolline'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
  gem 'pry-exception_explorer'
end
```

Google the gems, see if they can optimize your process.